# Get AJAX Request and Create Div Only Once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Using JavaScript, how can I get an AJAX request and create div *only* once? As you can see in this example, the AJAX request is received everytime you click on the button, and the div is also created: http://jsfiddle.net/2uvms99o/

**HTML**:

```
<button onclick="test();">Press Me</button>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function test() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = 'This is a div!';
            document.body.appendChild(div);
        }
    });
}
```

Maybe there's a better way to do this rather than `onclick`?

Comment: Why are you using inline binding rather than $("button").one("click", test)

Comment: I wasn't sure which one is the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand your problem two ways, the first is:

> How do I only create the `<div>` once?

To which I'd suggest that you test for the existence of the created `<div>` element in the `success` function, if it already exists then use it, if it doesn't exist then create it:

```
success: function (data) {

    // if the element with the id of 'ajaxResponse'
    // doesn't exist in the DOM:
    if (!document.getElementById('ajaxResponse')) {

        // we create the <div> element:
        var div = document.createElement('div');

        // give it the id that we're looking for:
        div.id = 'ajaxResponse';

        // append it to the document.body:
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }

    // find the element we want to work with (the <div> we
    // created, above:
    var responseDiv = document.getElementById('ajaxResponse');

    // set its innerHTML:
    responseDiv.innerHTML = "This is a div.";
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2uvms99o/3/);

The alternative is:

> How can I prevent more than one ajax request being initiated?

To which I'd suggest that in the success function you simply disable the `<button>`:

```
success: function (data) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = 'This is a div!';
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    // using document.querySelector, with a CSS attribute-
    // selector to select the first button with an 'onclick'
    // attribute; obviously change this to a selector
    // appropriate for use-case. And we then set the
    // disabled state to true (to prevent subsequent interaction):
    document.querySelector('button[onclick]').disabled = true;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2uvms99o/4/).

Comment: I like both of these solutions, especially the second one as it disables the button too. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery provides [`$.fn.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method exactly for this purpose: it unbinds event after it has been fired for the first time:

```
$('button').one('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = 'This is a div!';
            document.body.appendChild(div);
        }
    });
});
```

This is also preferred approach since you don't use obtrusive inline event handler attributes, thus you keep HTML clean. Just make sure you bind this event using more specific CSS selector (by id, class, parent, etc.), you don't want all buttons on the page to create divs on click.

Comment: The selector is an id while it should be a tag ( according to the html )

Comment: He should add an id to the html, this isn't suppose to be taken word for word

Comment: I agree. But this can ( and I think will ) create a confusion in case the user tries to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a check to check its already run or not

```
var run = true;
function test() {
    if(run){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = 'This is a div!';
            document.body.appendChild(div);
        }
    });
        run = false;
    }

}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/farhanbaloch/2uvms99o/1/

Comment: While this is a solution, this does not promotes the best approach.

Comment: Yeah, we can also bind event and once it triggered then unbind that event

Comment: but i think there should be some check to test its run already or not

Answer (score 0):

If you can specify an `id` to the `div` you are creating, you can check whther that element already exists before creating it,

```
success: function (data) {
            if (!($("#myDiv").length)) {    // Check whether #myDiv exists
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML = 'This is a div!';
                div.id = "myDiv";    // Specify an id for the div
                document.body.appendChild(div);
            }
        }
```